# How do i display the video using play button , making the preview screen from smaller to larger when clicked on play

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display the video using click to play button which pops up a window. [As seen here](http://edition.cnn.com/2012/10/01/sport/motorsport/motorsport-schumacher-sauber-hamilton/index.html?hpt=hp_t3). Currently I am using iframe to display the video. How to do that using html, css?

Currently this is the code to display the video

```
<div class="player">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?= $vimeo;?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=abcc16&amp;autoplay=0" width="250" height="250" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using pure javascript, or another javascript framework (such as jQuery, MooTools, etc...) ?

Comment: The example you have provided DOES NOT pop up a window.

Comment: I did not use anything for now to display.I am new to them.

Comment: When i Click on play its working in Internet Explorer

Comment: I see the preview getting bigger with an animation and then it starts playing. Chrome. Is this what you want or you need new window?

Comment: Did you try the answer by think123 ? I'll suggest that you replace :
<input type="button" onclick="openmovie();" value="Click to Play" />
By : 
<div id="playVideoButton" onclick="openmovie();return false;"></div>

Comment: yeah i need the preview getting bigger with an animation and starts playing, this is what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openmovie() {
  window.open("yourmovieaddress", "movieclicked", "width=yourwidth,height=yourheight,toolbars=no,status=no,resize=no");
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="openmovie();" value="Click to Play" />
```

Customize the styling and parameters to your own needs.

Since you want an animation, take a look into jQuery. That'll help.

Comment: sorry, can you please tell me how can i get the preview getting bigger with an animation and starts playing without the pop up